# Computing π to "infinite" binary precision in C#

Tags: c#, haskell, pi

So far it looks like Fabrice Bellard's base 2 equation is the way to go

[image]

Ironically this will require a BigReal type; do we have this for .Net? .Net 4.0 has BigInteger.

Anyone have a Haskell version?

Comment: Not sure if this is of any interest to you: http://pebblesteps.com/post/Calculating-PI-using-the-Monte-Carlo-method-using-F.aspx

Comment: "What is your motive? :) – zproxy"

- ulterior

Comment: I do not think you understand what "infinite" actually means :-)

Comment: I'm assuming he meant arbitrary, not infinite.

Comment: I seem to recall that 3.14159 was enough to calculate the circumference of the Earth to the accuracy of a car length. Someone once wrote that about 20 significant digits was enough to calculate the volume of the galaxy to the size of an atom (it may not be 20 (my memory's not the best) but it was certainly relatively small). Do you really need more accuracy than that?

Comment: If you're after some mathematical/programming challenges, checkout the Euler Project. If you're after us making your homework, please tag the question as "homework"

Comment: Brann: I have no interest in anyone doing any homework for me. That ended years ago, thank you very much.

Comment: Did someone alter my question to change from infinite to arbitrary precision? Actually I meant infinite, as in infinite stream. No I will get access the infinite digit, but I will have an abstraction over an infinite series.

Comment: Can "moderators" freely alter my post? This is not cool. At least there should be revision control and it should clearly show what was altered as well as my ability to veto changes.

Comment: @Bent : anybody with more than 3k rep can alter your post. You can see the revision history using the "edited" link on your post, and rollback if needed. Please check out the faq (link at the very bottom of this page) for more information on this.

Comment: @Bent : I edited your question title to reflect the comments you made in my answer. Update/Rollback if needed

Comment: @Bent : oh and btw, regarding homework, please don't take this the wrong way. Being interested in this kind of problems as a hobby is fine (as is asking for homework help, btw)

Comment: If you really meant "infinite", then it is not clear why you mention `BigReal` - the latter isn't infinite, it's arbitrarily large (given memory constraints), but still finite.

Comment: ... and it's definitely not streaming.

Comment: You are right Pavel, but that is sort of what I wanted to arrive at. I think definiting arithmetic operations on bitstreams would do the trick. It's silly in practical terms, but I want to try the simplest possible model for an infinite series of bits of π. Not it'll never be infinite but a stream does *model* something which is infinite, even if it itself never can be.

Comment: Thanks for the info Brann. I also think asking about homework is fine, at least if you are honest about it, although I see many people annoyed about it. This is purely hobby programming though.

Comment: "Infinite" means "without limit".  "Infinite precision" is the same as "arbitrary precision" - in neither case is there an inherent limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're asking for a Haskell version, [here is a paper](http://karczmarczuk.users.greyc.fr/arpap/lazypi.pdf) by Jerzy Karczmarczuk, called "The Most Unreliable Technique in the World to compute π":

> This paper is an atypical exercice in
>   lazy functional coding, written  for
>   fun and instruction. It can be read
>   and understood by anybody  who
>   understands the programming language
>   Haskell. We show how to  implement the
>   Bailey-Borwein-Ploue formula for π
>   in a co-recursive,  incremental way
>   which produces the digits 3, 1, 4, 1,
>   5, 9. . . until the  memory
>   exhaustion. This is not a way to
>   proceed if somebody needs  many
>   digits! Our coding strategy is
>   perverse and dangerous, and it 
>   provably breaks down. It is based on
>   the arithmetics over the domain  of
>   infinite sequences of digits
>   representing proper fractions expanded
>   in an integer base. We show how to
>   manipulate: add, multiply by an 
>   integer, etc. such sequences from the
>   left to the right ad infinitum, 
>   which obviously cannot work in all
>   cases because of ambiguities. Some 
>   deep philosophical consequences are
>   discussed in the conclusions.

It doesn't really solve the problem in an efficient or very practical way, but is entertaining and shows some of the problems with lazy infinite precision arithmetic.

Then there's also [this paper by Jeremy Gibbons](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/metamorphisms-scp.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This exactly the kind of stuff I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

By far my favorite Haskell spigot for pi comes from Jeremy Gibbons:

```
pi = g(1,0,1,1,3,3) where
    g(q,r,t,k,n,l) = 
        if 4*q+r-t<n*t
        then n : g(10*q,10*(r-n*t),t,k,div(10*(3*q+r))t-10*n,l)
        else g(q*k,(2*q+r)*l,t*l,k+1,div(q*(7*k+2)+r*l)(t*l),l+2)
```

The mathematical background that justifies that implementation can be found in:

[A Spigot Algorithm for the Digits of Pi](http://www.mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/spigot.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia details a lot of ways to get numerical approximations of pi [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_approximations_of_%CF%80). They also give some sample pseudo-code

Edit : If you're interested in this kind of mathematical problems without having any related real-world problem to solve (which is definitely a good attitude to have, IMHO), you could visit the [Euler Project page](http://projecteuler.net/)

Comment: Sorry, you misread my question. I'm not after anything within the range of native types. I want true "BigNum" π.

Comment: I'm also not after a "baked" solution, just genuine input/ideas about this. I didn't think I was the only person on Stackoverflow to be interested in this kind of thing in my spare time.

Comment: @Bent. This is a classic math problem. It's covered extensively in the wikipedia page I posted, and I honestly doubt you will get some guenuinely new ideas here. What exactly are you after ?

Comment: Don't get hung up over the term "approximation." Any representation, even one that is arbitrarily (not infinitely) precise, is still a numerical approximation.

Comment: I agree with that Jimmy but I still think using the term infinite is acceptable given that streams do in fact model infinite series, even if they can never be realized. But it doesn't really matter. I think .Net lacks a "native" BigReal type (one that comes with the BCL).

Answer (score 2):

There exists such possibility to process big rational numbers in [DLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime)-based dynamic languages (e.g. [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=IronPython)). Or you can use any portable C/C++ implementation of big real numbers through [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P/Invoke).